# Modify (bold) all words before a certain word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a list of near 1000 awards to appear on a site. Each award is in it's own span, and follows the format

```
x for y
```

example:

```
<span>Broadcast Film Critics Association Award for Best Director</span>
```

For each of these spans, I would like to bold all the text before "for". How can I search for an unlimited possible number of words before (and not including) the word(not just characters) "for", and bold them?

I know with an expression like

```
\S+\s+\S+\s+for
```

I am searching up to 2 words before (and including) the characters f, o, and r. But I want to match the word "for", and not just the characters, and I don't want to include "for" in what is being bolded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex would seem to be the best solution here, however I would suggest using a Regex which matches groups so you can rebuild the string when adding the `<b>` tags in. Try this:

```
$('span').html(function(i, v) {
    var matches = /(.+)(for.+)/gi.exec(v);
    return '<b>' + matches[1] + '</b>' + matches[2];
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdokv4xe/)

Comment: Good call on aggressively matching too; question of whether reluctant vs. aggressive match depends on the data of course

Comment: This works great for me! If you don't mind, I'm trying to breakdown how it works (I'm new to regex). Could you point out if I'm understanding any of this wrong? `/ /` contains the expression itself. `(.+)` matches a group of every character not included in the second group. `(for.+)` matches a group of every character starting with the word "for" and continuing forward. `gi` searches all matches before returning, and matches are not case-sensitive. `.exec(v)` takes the regex and creates an array out of the 2 different groups. What does the `v` in `.exec(v)` do?

Comment: `v` is the current html value, as provided by jquerys `html()` method

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that everything before the very first `for` is what you need to match.  If you worry about more than one `for` in the string, you'll need a different solution.

```
(.*?\b)for
```

This is "reluctantly match and capture everything up to the first word break followed by `for`."

http://rubular.com/r/OLNZjkA2ck

You could also use

```
.*?\b(?=for)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do regex [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to achieve it as below.

```
$('span').html(function(index, content) {
    return content.replace(/(.+)(for.+)/gi, '<strong>$1</strong>$2');
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfpsyrnL/)